# Include a dailymotion video in Cornerstone

Tags: wordpress, video, dailymotion-api, cornerstone

I have a video on Dailymotion that I'd like to display on my Wordpress website (X-Theme with Cornerstone).

I use a Video Player element and when I paste the URL of the video in the *SRC & Poster* field no video is being displayed.

[image]

I don't know much about this so I am open to any suggestions. (Is there maybe an other element which is more appropriate for this ? )

I chose DailyMotion rather than Youtube because I need an annotation linking to a page from my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Embedded video feature of the x theme to integrate/add the dailymotion video:

Use the following code inside the Embedded video in the embed code section and replace the video ID.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270"
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xwr14q?autoplay=1&mute=1"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[Screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2469908/496072c987149bf15b731aef358ad6c7)